# Changing the backgound of a lot of images in GIMP of Pixelmator

Tags: macos, gimp, pixelmator

How do I bulk change the background of the images to White. I have 400 Images of jewelry in which I want to batch edit them to change their background.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to use a [batch script](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) to accomplish that.
How difficult this is depends on the individual images.
If they all have, for example, black cloth backgrounds it won't be easy. but not impossible. If all the backgrounds are different,it will be significantly harder